# How to delete 1000s of duplicated images in Wordpress?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images, wp-cli

We kinda have a wired problem that took me weeks of searching and testing, the problem is that while working on one of my client's Wordpress website I noticed that there are around 75k images in February 2018 in Wordpress Media, I went to delete them on Folder /2018/02 thinking that this will be an easy way to do it but I found that the folder is empty!

Now somehow WordPress says that there are all these images in that month that they're basically duplicated images, So I went to delete all the unattached files using CLI with this code:

```
wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='attachment' --format=ids --post_parent=0)
```

The sad thing was that the data entry team working with my client didn't attach most images to their products, and we lost the images for over 3k products.

Now I restored an old backup to fix the missing images, but we still have all these duplicated images which we can't delete from SQL, File Manager, and also CLI, the only way to delete them is through Wordpress Dashboard and that will break the website because it won't handle 999 images being deleted at once and also will take a long time to do.

**The million-dollar question is** How can we delete all the images in **February 2018** without touching any other product images? and without breaking the website for too long?

Sorry for the lengthy question but it's a really tricky issue.

Comment: You need to hire somebody. You're not using technical words correctly, so it's impossible to tell you what to do.

Comment: I didn't mention that I'm an expert or something and if we should hire someone that would be great, but why are you assuming that it's impossible to tell me what to do?

Comment: Your console query is simply deleting all attachments, which is not what you want - right? You need to specify the date range of February 2018, then it should work. You can either do the query via WP-CLI or in phpmyadmin or write your own sql query in a php file and fire that one time. Yes, that is tricky and you need to know what you are doing. Clone the system, try it on localhost until the query works like intended. Execute the query live.